# WCF location seen in a test

Tags: wcf, testing

WCF project in a Test harness.

Why would HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/"); or 
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".");

fail in my test?

I am attempting to put together a PDF building module for existing app.  I have to identify where to write the final output.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your unit tests are failing is because [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) requires an ASP.NET context which is close to impossible to recreate in a unit test. Frameworks such as ASP.NET MVC abstract away this using [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) which can be easily mocked in an unit test.

Also you shouldn't be using `HttpContext` in WCF. If you self host your WCF service it will blow not only in the unit tests but at execution which is even worse.

Conclusion:

- Every time you write `HttpContext.Current` in a method by definition this method is not unit testable so don't even try to test it.
- Never use `HttpContext.Current` in WCF (and if you read the previous point, not only in WCF :-))

Comment: Will use relativePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;  

Thanks